# What is NoRel heuristic in GUROBI?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi, heuristics

There is NoRel (or No Relaxation) heuristic in the Gurobi solver which helps to find very good feasible solutions for Mixed Integer Programs. I couldn't find explanation of its idea. Perhaps anybody knows the details? Or it is a commercial secret and there is no paper describing it? I found out some information here: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/9341291193745-NoRel-heuristics-is-this-adding-valid-inequalities-, but it is not sufficient.

Comment: You need to watch the videos from Gurobi describing the release of v9. What they do is randomly fix a large portion of the integer variables and solve for the rest. They do this repeatedly and in parallel.

Comment: @Brannon, thank you, now it is clear what this heuristic does.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/9282521673745-What-is-phase-1-solution-

You can also read this one, might help you.